# What's an easy way to trim N lines from the tail of a file (without the use of 'head')?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, scripting

Say I've got a bunch of files that are all >100 lines long.  I'd like to trim off the top 14 lines and the bottom 9 lines, leaving only the lines in the middle.  This command will trim off the top fourteen:

```
cat myfile.txt | tail -n +15
```

Is there another command I can pipe through to trim off the bottom 9 without explicitly passing the length of the file?

Edited to add:  My version of head (Mac OS 10.5) doesn't accept a negative number of lines as a parameter.

Comment: This is also a 'gratuitous use of cat' error - tail takes a filename as an argument as well.

Comment: Harper, i thought about writing that into my answer, but then i saw that it makes it less readable. having the cat at the beginning, then piping through head & tail is more readable than placing the filename as argument to head imho

Comment: Is readability a concern for script one-liners? Heck, the accepted sed answer is, IMHO, a lot less readable than tail -n +15 myfile.txt |head -n -9 .

Comment: are you sure about the +15? this will only remove 14 lines from, as it "starts the display at the" 15th line.

Comment: @Harper As a matter of context for my particular problem, the cat at the beginning makes the entire script more readable, which is one reason I prefer it.  (The previous and next lines after this command need cat.)

Comment: @hop Good catch, I'll edit to correct.  Thanks.  I had some wiggle room that meant I didn't need to double check the exact number of lines, so my mistake wasn't affecting me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work on OS X and might be a bit more easily understandable than the `sed` example:

```
< myfile.txt tail -n +15 | tail -r | tail -n +10 | tail -r
```

Of course, if you can get your hands on GNU's version of `head`, it can be done even more elegantly:

```
< myfile.txt tail -n +15 | head -n -9
```

Be aware the `tail` *starts* at the nth line while `head` *skips* n lines of the input.

Answer (score 4):

You could use sed:

```
sed -n -e :a -e '1,9!{P;N;D;};N;ba' myfile.txt
```

You can also use sed for the first 15:

```
sed '1,15d' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative number of lines with the `head` command:

```
cat myfile.txt | head -n  -9
```

That prints everything except the last 9 lines.

Comment: OSX head does not support a negative number of lines.

Comment: "OSX head does not support a negative number of lines." That's true, but when this answer was written, the question didn't clearly say that it must run on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

What jbourque said is completely right. He just wasn't too wordy about it:

```
cat myfile.txt | tail -n +15 | head -n -9
```

Comment: Much as I hate upvoting those with a higher rep :-), this is exactly what I would have said if I'd turned the computer on 5 minutes earlier this morning. +1.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac. (...but original question didn't state that solution must work on Mac, so it's OK I guess...)

Answer (score 2):

If you can recognize the last 9 lines by a distinctive pattern for the first of those lines, then a simple `sed` command would do the trick:

```
sed -e '1,15d' -e '/distinctive-pattern/,$d' $file
```

If you need a pure numeric offset from the bottom, standard (as opposed to GNU) `sed` won't help, but `ed` would:

```
ed $file <<'!'
1,15d
$-8,$d
w
q
!
```

This overwrites the original files.  You'd have to script where the file is written to if you wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The `head` command should do what you want.  It woks just like `tail` but from the other end of the file.

Comment: head appears to only let me display the first N lines, which is different from trimming the last N lines.  (I don't know exactly how many lines I need to see, just that I need to get rid of the last 9.)

Comment: head outputs some lines from the beginning - with positive argument, it returns n lines, with negative argument, it returns all but (first) n lines. Tail is similar.

Comment: On OSX 10.10.5, with BSD `head` (June 29, 2006 version), `head -n` does **not** take a negative argument.  Presumably this was the case in 10.5.  On CentOS 6.6 with GNU coreutils (I have version 8.4) `head -n` **does** take a negative argument

Answer (score 0):

This should also work, and does things in a single process:

```
seq 15 | 
awk -v N=5 '
  { lines[NR % N] = $0 } 
  END { i = NR-N+1; if (i<0) i=0; for (; i <= NR; ++i) print lines[i % N] }'
```

(The `seq` is just an easy way to produce some test data.)